# arrêter court et dans toutes ses fugues

Tags: sens

> Avec une douzaine de propositions de cette espèce, et une presse
> libre, je voudrais arrêter court, dans toutes ses fugues, le
> gouvernement du 2 décembre.

Je ne comprends pas *arrêter court et dans toutes ses fugues*.

Voici l'extrait complet :

[image]

Comment: Ça serait mieux de citer aussi la source de cet extrait. Merci !

Comment: Je viens d'ajouter la source de cette phrase. (J'espère que c'est ça:-)!). 
N'hésitez pas à ajouter plus de nuances.

Answer (score 1):

*Arrêter court* signifie "arrêter de manière nette". *Court* est ici utilisé comme adverbe (cf. sens II C 1 [ici](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/court/1)).

*Fugue* a le sens de "fuite". Dans le contexte mentionné, le sens est plutôt métaphorique, l'auteur dit vouloir arrêter le gouvernement lorsqu'il semble prendre la fuite.